# How to top up with coupon in Woo Wallet Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I used Woo Wallet plugin in my woocommerce website. There is an option for wallet top up. However, I want to make an option for top up with coupon. Looking forward for an answer from senior developers here. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is Subrata from WooWalle team. Currently, WooWallet doesn't support wallet top-up via coupon code but we are building a paid add-on to support this feature.